# Upgrade to Rails 3 and lost ability to run Active Record database migrations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, mongoid, rake

I have a corporate web application that, for various reasons, has Active Record connections to SQL Server as well as Mongoid Documents. There has been resistance to updating to Rails 3 until now (yes, I know, just in time for Rails 4). The app is mostly working fine and both databases play well with each other. However, I seem to have lost the ability to run SQL database migrations.

`rake -T` gives me the following db options:

```
rake db:drop                      # Drops all the collections for the database for the current Rails.env
rake db:mongoid:create_indexes    # Create the indexes defined on your mongoid models
rake db:mongoid:drop              # Drops the database for the current Rails.env
rake db:mongoid:purge             # Drop all collections except the system collections
rake db:mongoid:remove_indexes    # Remove the indexes defined on your mongoid models without questions!
rake db:purge                     # Drop all collections except the system collections
rake db:reseed                    # Delete data and seed
rake db:seed                      # Load the seed data from db/seeds.rb
rake db:setup                     # Create the database, and initialize with the seed data
```

`rake db:migrate` just returns without any information whatsoever.

It looks like the mongoid gem might be the culprit as migrations work fine with a blank project and the only db options are mongoid related.

My question is: How do I restore ActiveRecord migrations after upgrading to rails 3 and mongoid 3.1.3?

Comment: Update: I have even tried `rails g migration` and the new migration is not picked up on either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, at least the missing rake tasks part.

Turns out you need to have the `require 'rails/all'` in your `config/application.rb` file.

This returns the db tasks to rake.